# In spring block system, how $∆K = - ∆V$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, potential-energy, spring

According to law of conservation of mechanical energy,

$\Delta K + \Delta V = 0$
or
$\Delta K = -\Delta V$

but when in spring block system $\Delta K = 0$, and at both initial and final positions $K = 0$, $\Delta V{\rm(potential\ energy)}\ne 0$.
This implies $\Delta K \ne \Delta V$, which is wrong.
Please tell what I am missing.
Spring is placed horizontally.
[image]
In condition a, total energy is zero. While in condition b, there is some amount of V.

Comment: In a spring block, change in potential energy implies change in kinetic energy. Agreed. Now, what are the initial and final positions you are referring to? Perhaps you can make a sketch.

Comment: @npojo What do you mean by "In a spring block, change in potential energy implies change in kinetic energy." Added sketch.

Comment: In order for state a to shift to state b, without an external force, you must have velocity at state a. In this case, the velocity at state b is lower than at state a but the potential energy is higher. If at state a the velocity is zero and an external force shifts from a to b, then conservation of energy within the spring system is not conserved.

Comment: @npojo Thanks, it was a basic confusion and a foolish question. You should add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for state *a* to shift to state *b*, without an external force, you must have velocity at state *a*. In this case, the velocity at state *b* is lower than at state *a* but the potential energy is higher.

If at state *a* the velocity is zero and an external force shifts from *a* to *b*, then conservation of energy **within** the spring system cannot be applied.

Answer (score 2):

The law of conservation  of mechanical energy states that the total mechanical energy at any point in the motion is **constant**. It never says it's 0.

$\text{K.E. + P.E. = constant}$.

If total energy was 0, motion would have never taken place.

Comment: You can choose a zero of potential energy such that the given sum does equal zero?

Comment: @WrichikBasu I have placed ∆ before K & V, refering change in kinetic and potential energy.